# Set image background to shape on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to take [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1136236) example and change the color of every sperm to an image.

In the example they colored all the sperms in white color, and I want to put an image instead.

How can i do this?

I have android application that I should add the script to it, so I work on Eclipse and I saved the images in the asset folder.

If I change the background to image it works good, but every try to change the sperm background doesn't work for me.

Thanks for help!

**Edit 1 :**

This is a try to do it inside the CSS :

```
ellipse {
    background-image:url('head.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And this is the try to do it inside the script

```
var head = g.append("ellipse")
    .attr("rx", 26.5)
    .attr("ry", 24)
    .attr("xlink:href", "/assets/head.png");
```

Comment: Why you want to colorize the sperm anyway?

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have done?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I want to put an image instead of the white color to get a better looking sperm.

Comment: Ahhh stylish ones, hope you are not looking forward to make them wear different props as well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use svg:image instead of ellipse

```
var head = g.append("svg:image")
    .attr('x',-11)
    .attr('y',-11)
    .attr('width', 22)
    .attr('height', 22)
    .attr("xlink:href","http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/smile/super-smile-smiley-emoticon.gif")
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qK9K8/2/

Comment: My problem is that i don't want dependency on internet connection so **.attr("xlink:href","http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/smile/super-smile-smiley-emoticon.gif")** this line is not good for me

Comment: You can put relative path for sure. I just putted some image from internet to show in demo.

Comment: I tried this line .attr("xlink:href", "assets/head"); but i just get black ellipse

Comment: Your file cannot be named "head", you have to change to "assets/head.png" or "assets/head.gif" I don't know. Also check the path, maybe you need "../assets/head.png" for example

Comment: OK, I forget to change to "svg:image" now it works fine ! Thank you very much

Comment: Just one more question, Is this possible to set image on the tail?

Comment: :-D Your imagination is perfect. I can't imagine how it should looks like. Create screenshot, maybe I will be able to do some magic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50026/discussion-between-hayk-mantashyan-and-user2235615)

Comment: this is awesome. Hayk :)